# Digging out septic lid but going through unexpected material

Tags: septic

I bought this house with a septic system two months ago, and we had the septic system inspected, which left two clear dug-up areas in the lawn. I am digging up what I think is the inlet lid (closer to the house) for a few reasons, right in the same spot they dug. I found a round, black plastic circle that I assumed was the lid and started digging out the rest of it (probably about 24" diameter)... but, there's no handle apparent, and what really concerns me is that in at least some of the places I seem to be going through a thick, play-dough like material that is distinctly red and white layered (red on top, white below. The soil is pretty thick red clay, but this stuff is different and doesn't seem natural. Am I going through some kind of liner that is now damaged? Is this not the lid?

*Edit: Adding photos*

[image: Septic tank lid (?) with red & white substance]
[image: Slice of red & white substance]

Comment: Pictures please.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Pictures added...

Comment: Once you've dug it up, consider saving yourself the trouble next time (and there's always a next time) by installing a riser for that lid.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like adobe with some iron in the soil, I have never seen a “seal layer” like you ask about check the edges there are notches many times you can use a bar to pry the lid open.